# I need to import the Wechat Public Account Articles to Wordpress posts or blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs, article, wechat

How to import content of the like public article [here](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/xgKGEx85vHgyEPvIQGlINA) into Wordpress blogs? how I can do that? are there there any plugins ffor that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library etc. are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are no plugin for that as far as I'm aware. You'd have to use the WeChat API (after authentication etc) to get the Permanent Assets as described in the official documentation (https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/Asset_Management/Getting_Permanent_Assets.html).